# Correlation of an image

Tags: image, matlab

I tried to using this post [How to find Correlation of an image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3689840/how-to-find-correlation-of-an-image)

to find Correlation for my image but i have questions.when i use this: cov(x,y) / ( sqrt(D(x)* D(y) )) my result is  [1.0025   -0.0358 ;-0.0358    0.9975](for 5000 pixel).  -0.0358 is Correlation for my image?what is 0.9975?i run my code tow times. the second result is  [0.9830   0.0243;0.0243    1.0173].-0.0358 or 0.0243 which one is Correlation ? I know because of using randperm In each run different number is create but Which one is a best?negative number or positive number?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Functions like `corrcoef` return values like [1.0025 -0.0358; -0.0358 0.9975] where the coefficient is -0.0358, and the other values relate to the certainty of the coefficient.

Here's what you should expect from the covariance matrix `cov`:
http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cov.html

Here's what you should expect from the correlation coefficients `corrcoef`:
http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/corrcoef.html

What I suspect is going on is there's some variable whose value is affected by running.  A useful debugging practice (when going through your code with a fine-toothed comb) is having your code output to the screen some of the values as they are being generated.  In Matlab, this is as simple as removing a few `;` at the end of a few lines.

Hope this helps!